# How to build React app and export files into /var/html/www folder?

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I have a React app in /srv/app folder, when I build the app, it generates the built files into "public" folder within the same app folder.

I need to run npm run build and build the files into the /var/html/www/app folder. so I can redirect a subdomain to it or access it through (sub.domain.com/app).

I put this in the packaje file

```
{
...  "homepage":"/var/html/www/app",
...
```

also tried:

```
"homepage":"."
```

and

```
"homepage":"./"
```

and

```
"homepage":"/"
```

but it didn't generate the files there.

any help?

thanks

Comment: You just manually move the content of "public" folder into "/var/html/www/app", that's it.

Comment: If you want to automate that part, assume you use `npm run build`, which in turn calls the script that's specified in `package.json` -> `"scripts.build"` field, you can simply add `&& cp public/* "/var/html/www/app"` to the end of it.